# Verify a subnet mask for validity in Python

Tags: python, reinventing-the-wheel, ip-address

I've written a small Python function to check whether a string is a valid IPv4 subnet mask.

It works but maybe it's too convoluted and terse? Or maybe it could be improved / optimised / rewritten in a cleverer way than just to check 1's in a string?..

IsIPv4Address is another function of mine (**EDIT 1**: added it into the question).
I specifically don't want to use any libraries / external functions as this is rather a study in Python :)

```
def IsIPv4Address(ipAdd):
    """Validate an IPv4 address"""
    octets = ipAdd.split(".")
    if len(octets) != 4:
        return False
    for octet in octets:
        if not IsInteger(octet):
            return False
        if int(octet) > 255 or int(octet) < 0:
            return False

    return True


def IsIPv4Mask(ipMask):
    """Validate an IPv4 subnet mask"""

    # Each mask looks like an IPv4 address and must pass the checks
    if not IsIPv4Address(ipMask):
        return False

    ipMaskBinary = ""
    ipMaskBinary = ipMaskBinary.join([bin(int(oct))[2:] for oct in ipMask.split(".")])

    isBitZero = ipMask[0] == "0"
    for bit in ipMaskBinary[1:]:
        if bit == "1" and isBitZero:
                return False

        if bit == "0":
            isBitZero = True

    return True
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As recommended in PEP 8, the official style guide, [function names should be `lower_case_with_underscores`](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#function-and-variable-names) unless you have a good reason for making an exception.

Functions like this are perfect places to write [doctests](https://docs.python.org/3/library/doctest.html), to explain how the function should behave while providing unit tests at the same time.

---

The `IsIPv4Address()` function is easy to implement.  I would take advantage of the [`all()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#all) function with a [generator expression](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html#generator-expressions) and a [double-ended inequality](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#comparisons).

```
def is_ipv4_address(dotquad):
    """
    Validate an IPv4 address in dotted-quad notation.

    >>> is_ipv4_address("1.2.3.4")
    True
    >>> is_ipv4_address("127.0.0.1/8")
    False
    >>> is_ipv4_address("1.2.3.4.5")
    False
    >>> is_ipv4_address("1.2.3")
    False
    >>> is_ipv4_address("1.2.3.256")
    False
    >>> is_ipv4_address("1.2.3.-4")
    False
    >>> is_ipv4_address("fe80::")
    False
    """
    octets = dotquad.split(".")
    return len(octets) == 4 and \
           all(o.isdigit() and 0 <= int(o) < 256 for o in octets)
```

---

The netmask verifier is trickier to write well.  You have chosen to use `bin()` to stringify the 32-bit number.  I'd avoid using strings for something that can be done arithmetically, since string manipulation is relatively inefficient.

Furthermore, I'd suggest that instead of writing just a validation function, you may as well write a function to tell you the length of the netmask, since it's nearly the same amount of work, but you can get more useful information that way.

```
def ipv4_mask_len(dotquad):
    """
    Finds the number of bits set in the netmask.

    >>> ipv4_mask_len("255.255.255.0")
    24
    >>> ipv4_mask_len("0.0.0.0")
    0
    >>> ipv4_mask_len("255.255.255.255")
    32
    >>> ipv4_mask_len("127.0.0.0")
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      ...
    ValueError: Invalid netmask: 127.0.0.0
    """
    if not is_ipv4_address(dotquad):
        raise ValueError("Invalid netmask: {0}".format(dotquad))
    a, b, c, d = (int(octet) for octet in dotquad.split("."))
    mask = a << 24 | b << 16 | c << 8 | d

    if mask == 0:
        return 0

    # Count the number of consecutive 0 bits at the right.
    # https://wiki.python.org/moin/BitManipulation#lowestSet.28.29
    m = mask & -mask
    right0bits = -1
    while m:
        m >>= 1
        right0bits += 1

    # Verify that all the bits to the left are 1's
    if mask | ((1 << right0bits) - 1) != 0xffffffff:
        raise ValueError("Invalid netmask: {0}".format(dotquad))
    return 32 - right0bits
```

Comment: You should pass a value for maxsplit so that split can terminate early on degenerate input.

Comment: Thanks @200_success! I knew that string-parsing is not the best solution :)

Answer (score 3):

`IsIPv4Address` should pass a value of 3 for `maxsplit` on your `split` call.

Most of that function (after the len check) can be condensed to:

```
return all(IsInteger(o) and 0 <= o < 256 for o in octets)
```

Your `IsIPv4Mask` should probably be done in a very different manner - rather than string-ifying the octets to binary text, it should convert the words to a single 32-bit integer (as is done everywhere else), for efficiency. At that point, write a loop that

- checks the current LSB
- shifts the integer by 1
- loops until the integer is equal to 0

Answer (score 1):

The following code is so very ineffective, yet it will rarely matter, so I prefer it being less lines.

```
def is_ipv4_netmask(str):
    ip = ipaddress.IPv4Address(str)
    binmask = bin(int.from_bytes(ip.packed, "big"))
    return bool(re.match('^0b(1*)(0+)$', binmask))
```

Read properly the IPv4Network, and it's usable for me, so I'm doing the following, which also accepts host-masks in the form of "0.0.0.255" being equal to "255.255.255.0", thus I must let it normalize it to the latter form.

```
# raises ipaddress.NetmaskValueError for an invalid netmask
def normalize_ipv4_mask(mask):
    return str(ipaddress.IPv4Network((0, mask)).netmask)
```